# rpm -q --verify --nouser --nogroup --nomode --nomtime PACKAGENAME

Tags: security, deb

What is equivalent to following line in Ubuntu / Debian world ?

Note: I have original .deb files and i want to check which files differs from original zimbra-*.deb

```
for Z in $(rpm -qa | grep ^zimbra); do echo "Checking $Z"; rpm -q --verify --nouser --nogroup --nomode --nomtime $Z; done
```

This line grabbed from https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Investigating_and_Securing_Systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have original .deb files and i want to check which files differs
>   from original zimbra-*.deb

Checksums for files installed by a .deb are kept in a local database, and can be checked with the `debsums` command. Example:

```
$ debsums msmtp
/usr/bin/msmtp                                                                OK
/usr/share/doc/msmtp/Mutt+msmtp.txt                                           OK
/usr/share/doc/msmtp/NEWS.gz                                                  OK
/usr/share/doc/msmtp/README                                               FAILED
/usr/share/doc/msmtp/README.Debian                                            OK
....
```

the FAILED file was modified so the checksum doesn't match what's in the database.